# What do I do if launchpad repository doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository, launchpad

Recently, `ubuntu` told me that it failed to resynchronize the package index files from their sources. Here's the output of `apt-get update`:

```
...
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/attente/1218322/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/attente/1218322/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've got little or no experience with `launchpad`. That said, I figure the repository no longer exists. And if `1218322` is a repository name, then it's a strange one, isn't it? Anyway, 
probably it got [renamed](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch) to:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/attente/modifier-only-input-switch/ubuntu
```

In truth, I don't even remember adding this repository. It's in `sources.list.d/attente-1218322-saucy.list`. As far as I can tell, I have all the 3 packages installed, but they exist elsewhere (http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/). So I lean towards getting rid of this repository. And the other one I don't remember adding: sources.list.d/tuxpoldo-btsync-saucy.list, http://ppa.launchpad.net/tuxpoldo/btsync/ubuntu

P.S. Surprisingly, `apt-cache policy` still lists this repository as one of the options for `gnome-settings-daemon` as opposed to the other 2 packages:

```
$ apt-cache policy gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-settings-daemon:
  Installed: 3.8.5-0ubuntu11.2
  Candidate: 3.8.5-0ubuntu11.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.5-0ubuntu11.2 0
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.8.5-0ubuntu10ppa2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/attente/1218322/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.5-0ubuntu9 0
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

So, what am I to do? But addressing other issues I ran across along the way is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick `ppa attente/1218322` into Google, you'll end up at one of any number of pages that all seem to have the following notice:

> ***
>   The old PPA, ppa:attente/1218322 is superceded by the following one.
>   You can remove the old repository using ppa-purge.
>   ***
>
> PPA which should provide some relief for this issue is available at 
>   https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch. To install:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> (log out, log in)
> ```

So to interpret, run:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:attente/1218322
```

And if you want the newer version of:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on `apt-cache policy` still listing this repository? I did `apt-get update`, shouldn't it be gone from the cache?

Comment: The second half of the error: "They have been ignored, *or old ones used instead*". I imagine this is all cached up in `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`.